# SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition Installation Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am unable to install SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition on my laptop. It is currently on Windows 10 Home (Ver. 20H2 19042.928). According to the [SQL Server 2019 Software specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server-ver15?view=sql-server-ver15), Windows 10 Home is supported. But upon installation, I get the error:

```
The account that is running SQL server setup does not have one or both of the following rights: the right to backup files and directories, and the right to manage auditing and the security log. to continue, use an account with both of these rights.
```

The solution on the Microsoft website is to grant privileges via the *Local Group Policy* settings which is unavailable on Windows 10 Home. I tried to install it on both of my C and D drives but I still get the same error. How can I install it on my laptop?

Comment: Are you installing using an account that is a member of the Administrators group? When launching the installer are you right-clicking on it and choosing "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes. as per Accounts in my settings, my account is an administrator. And yes, whenever I click the installer, my computer always prompts to run it as an administrator first.

Comment: @rinrin, have you tried the resolution given in this Microsoft site? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/install/installation-fails-if-remove-user-right

Comment: @rinrin check this link to install Group policy editor in windows10 home edition. https://www.itechtics.com/enable-gpedit-windows-10-home/#:~:text=If%20the%20group%20policy%20editor,the%20settings%20of%20local%20computer.

Comment: @Annamalai I need a group policy setting. Is that safe? Seems like it's from a  third party website